# value replace adds value incorrectly to the end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a value replace in an input field. It is almost working correctly. The problem is it adds the value to the end of input when I only want it added to the one location

Html:

```
<input id="boom" value="03/15/0212" />​
```

Jquery: I have hard coded some values to keep from placing all functions

```
$('#boom').on('keypress', function (e)
{
    var crs = this.selectionStart;
    var from;
    var to;
    var sub;
    _dateSection = 'month';
    var currentObj = this;
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var stringSplit = currentVal.split('/');
    switch (_dateSection) {
        case 'month':
            _currentDateValue = stringSplit[0];
            from = 0;
            to = 2;
            sub = currentVal.substring(from, to);
            break;
        case 'day':
            _currentDateValue = stringSplit[1];
            from = 3;
            to = 6;
            sub = currentVal.substring(from, to);
            break;
        case 'year':
            _currentDateValue = stringSplit[2];
            from = 6;
            to = 10;
            sub = currentVal.substring(from, to);
            break;
    };
    var check = false;
    if (!check) {
        $(currentObj).val(function (index, value)
        {
            return value.replace(sub, c);
        });
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fC8KW/5/)

If you add 3 to the month portion of the input which is currently populated with 03 it replaces is correctly with 3, but it also adds 3 to the end of the year. Making the year, 20123 when the year value should remain 2012.

The final value should be

```
3/15/2012
```

not

```
3/15/20123
```

**Edit:**

this code gives the same problem:

```
$(currentObj).val(currentVal.replace(sub, c));
```

as does this

```
var replaceValue = currentVal.replace(sub, c)
$(currentObj).val(replaceValue);
```

Comment: why putting a function inside a val? this may introduce scope and enclosure problems

Comment: I updated Code and fiddle to not have function inside. still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra character that is added to the end is added by the input field itself. The keypress event is handled by the input also, which does the normal thing and adds the character to the value.

Just put `e.preventDefault();` in your event handler to keep the input from getting the event.

---

Also, don't use `replace` to put the character in the string, use `substr` to get the parts of the string that you want to keep:

```
value = value.substr(0, from) + c + value.substr(to, c);
```

If the string is for example `05/05/2012` and you try to replace the day with `4`, it will instead replace the first occurace and you get `4/05/2012` instead of `05/4/2012`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also thanks for the bonus info about replace and sub string

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:-

```
$('#boom').on('keyup', function (e)
            {
                var crs = this.selectionStart;
                var from;
                var to;
                var sub;
                _dateSection = 'month';
                var currentObj = this;
                var currentVal = $(this).val();
                var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                var stringSplit = currentVal.split('/');
                switch (_dateSection) {
                    case 'month':
                          _currentDateValue = stringSplit[0];
                          sub = _currentDateValue;
                         c=Number(sub)+Number(c);
                         break;
                    case 'day':
                        _currentDateValue = stringSplit[1];
                        from = 3;
                        to = 6;
                        sub = currentVal.substring(from, to);
                        break;
                    case 'year':
                        _currentDateValue = stringSplit[2];
                        from = 6;
                        to = 10;
                        sub = currentVal.substring(from, to);
                        break;
                };
                var check = false;
                if (!check) {
                    $(currentObj).val(function (index, value)
                    {

                        value=value.substring(from,value.length-1);
                        return value.replace(sub, c);
                    });
                }
        });
```

Comment: I think that replaces the last number as well. It appears that date becomes 3/15/2013 instead of 3/15/2012